# Exceeding matrix dimensions when averaging elements

Tags: matlab, indexing

I am trying to create a vector with the average of every 48 elements in eddyCO2.

```
Tweedle = eddyCO2(1:47:end);
Tweedle(1) = mean(eddyCO2(1):eddyCO2(48));
    for i = 2:length(Tweedle)
    Tweedle(i) = mean(eddyCO2((i-1)*48):eddyCO2(i*48)); (ERROR: Index exceeds matrix dimensions)
    end
```

I've tried reshaping and the only thing that seems to work is entering values manually but the size is too large to work without a loop. Why is this error appearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following modified version of your script do what you intend? Hope it helps.

```
Tweedle = eddyCO2(1:48:end);
sz = length(eddyCO2);
for i = 1:length(Tweedle)-1
    Tweedle(i) = mean(eddyCO2((i-1)*48+1):eddyCO2(i*48)); % averages elements 1-48, 49-96, etc.
end
Tweedle(i+1) = mean(eddyCO2(i*48+1):sz); % averages remaining items at end of vector
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked and got rid of my error :)